# XSD to validate the xml with Choice of attributeGroup

Tags: xml, xsd

Problem description :

I must optionally add a set of attributes to the existing Value element (see below).

Either sourceMsgType(Required) , sourceMsgVersion(Optional) ,destinationMsgType(Required) ,destinationMsgVersion(Optional) or suppressedSource(Required), suppressedMsgVersion(Optional) will be present.

I have tried with the following XSD but it shows the following error :

```
"**S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of '#AnonType_messageTypearchiveConfig' Is Invalid. Element 'choice' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.**".
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archiveConfig>
     <archivingStrategy>PURGE</archivingStrategy>
     <messageType sourceMsgType="STL01" sourceMsgVersion="" destinationMsgType="195" destinationMsgVersion="01" cutOff="90" filter ="N"/>
     <messageType sourceMsgType="STL01" destinationMsgType="CHESS197_01" cutOff="180"/> 
     <messageType sourceMsgType="STL03" destinationMsgType="101" destinationMsgVersion="02" cutOff="60" filter ="Y"/>
     <messageType suppressedSource="STL03" cutOff="60" filter ="Y"/>
     <messageType suppressedSource="STL01" suppressedMsgVersion="01" cutOff="60" filter ="Y"/>
</archiveConfig>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="archiveConfig">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="archivingStrategy"/>
        <xs:element name="messageType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="cutOff" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="filter" use="optional"/>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="setOfAttrs1" />
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="setOfAttrs2" />
                    <xs:assert test="(@sourceMsgType and @destinationMsgType 
                    and (@sourceMsgVersion or not(@sourceMsgVersion)) and (@destinationMsgVersion 
                    or not(@destinationMsgVersion)) not(@suppressedSource) and not(@suppressedMsgVersion))
                    or (@suppressedSource and (@suppressedMsgVersion or not(@suppressedMsgVersion)) 
                    and not(@sourceMsgType) and not(@sourceMsgVersion) and not(@destinationMsgType) and not(@destinationMsgVersion))"/> 
                </xs:choice>  
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:attributeGroup name="setOfAttrs1">
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="sourceMsgType" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="sourceMsgVersion" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="destinationMsgType" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="destinationMsgVersion" use="optional"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
  <xs:attributeGroup name="setOfAttrs2">
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="suppressedSource" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="suppressedMsgVersion" use="optional"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems in your xsd, but they all come from one incorrect assumption. You are assuming that an xs:choice can contain an attribute group.

In fact, a choice group is a type of 'model group' and model groups can only contain element, groups and wildcards. Not attributes. The details are all in the XML Schema specification. It's not easy to read, but it is the final authority on issues like this: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/

So you cannot achieve the exact validation rules that you are seeking, but you should be able to get close. Just make some of the attributes optional. If you need the rules to be validated strictly then you will need to do one of the following:

- add validation logic in your application to enforce the rules
- use a stronger XML validation language ( e.g. schematron/RelaxNG )

Alternatively, and only if the XML format is under your control, you could do any of the following:

- use tags instead of attributes to model these properties. Then you will be able to use a model group containing elements in your xs:choice.
- define a differently-named tag for the two variants of messageType ( messageType1 and messageType2 )
- if it is important to use the same tag name for the two variants, then define two global complex types which are both extensions of a base complex type. Then **in the XML** identify which complex type you want to validate against by adding an xsi:type attribute that specifies the complex type name.